# How can i change an SQL Query using Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm noob in PHP, and JQuery, and i'm trying to do a pagination without changing the page.

I could submit a form, but i want to change the value from the limit without doing a submission.

My Query(i want to change the Limit):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_day = '".$list_day."' AND event_month = '".$month."' AND event_year = '".$year."' LIMIT 0,3";
```

I tried to do that -

First, i created a form with the limit value:

```
$limit = 0;

<form id="more" method="GET">
<button type="button" id="more_btn" value="<?= $limit ?>" class="c-button-1"><</button>
</form>
```

And then, i tried to get the value from the button, using Ajax

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#more_btn",function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax( {

            type: 'get',
            url: "modules/groups/calendar.php",
            data: $('#more').serialize(),
            success: function( response ) {


            }
        });
    });
 });
```

I was thinking about getting the value from the button, and change it in JQuery:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_day = '".$list_day."' AND event_month = '".$month."' AND event_year = '".$year."' LIMIT ".$limit.",3";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't even need the `<form>` there. when you are working with `ajax` you generally don't need any forms unless you want to do some hybrid coding for browsers with javascript turned off, or for serializing them (what you tried).
but in your case it doesn't really make any sense since your form just contains one button.

and you are already trying to get the value from the button but don't use it later on for some reason. you don't need to use `.attr()` there, since `jQuery` got the `.val()`-function for HTML elements with the `value` attribute.

so i'd do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#more_btn",function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'get',
            url: "modules/groups/calendar.php",
            data: {
                my_button_value : value
            }
            success: function( response ) {
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

`$_GET['my_button_value']` then will receive the value in your PHP script.

in your question you also serialized the form which returns a URL-encoded string ("GET-style") which you can't just use in the `data`-attribute of the `$.ajax` function. you need an object there as i did in my code.

Comment: I would ommit the whole story about why you would or wouln't use `<form>` since that is not relevant for answering his question. And it also is redundant text for other readers. My advice: get more the to point. Since the answer is good enough.

Comment: @QuantumHive - well, i had to mention that he doesn't need it here since he got it in his html and tried to serialize it.

Comment: Maybe that kind of advice would be better suited in a comment?:)

Comment: @QuantumHive - i needed the advice in the answer since i needed to explain why i removed and replaced the `serialize()` in his javascript.